# Convert from ThreeJS geometry format 3 to 4: dealing with faces

Tags: json, three.js

I am having some problems with migration from ThreeJS geometry format 3 to 4. More specifically, i would like to manually create a surface in model.json file, but i don't get it to work.

in geometry format 3, the following code creates a single surface:

```
{
    "faces": [1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    "metadata": {
        "faces": 1
    },
    "vertices": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
}
```

Can some-one help me how to convert this to format 4?

The only example on geometry format 4 i could find was this one: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the equivalent code in json-geometry format 4:

```
{
  "vertices": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  "normals": [],
  "uvs": [],
  "faces": [ 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
}
```